# Finding matches in 2 files and printing the field above the match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

File1:

```
2987571 2988014
4663633 4668876
4669084 4669827
4669873 4670130
4670212 4670604
4670604 4672469
4672502 4672621
4672723 4673088
4673102 4673518
4673521 4673895
4679698 4680174
5756724 5757680
5757937 5758506
5758855 5759202
5759940 5771528
5772524 5773063
5773005 5773106
5773063 5773452
5773486 5773776
5773836 5774189
```

File2:

```
gene            complement(6864294..6865061)
                     /locus_tag="HCH_06747"
     CDS             complement(6864294..6865061)
                     /locus_tag="HCH_06747"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="ABC33372.1"
                     /translation="MIKQLVRPLFTGKGPNFSELSAKECGVGEYQLRYKLPGNTIHIG
                     MPDAPVPARVNLNADLFDSYGPKKLYNRTFVQMEFEKWAYKGRFLQGDSGLLSKMSLH
                     IDVNHAERHTEFRKGDLDSLELYLKKDLWNYYETERNIDGEQGANWEARYEFDHPDEM
                     RAKGYVPPDTLVLVRLPEIYERAPINGLEWLHYQIRGEGIPGPRHTFYWVYPMTDSFY
                     LTFSFWMTTEIGNRELKVQEMYEDAKRIMSMVELRKE"
     gene            complement(6865197..6865964)
                     /locus_tag="HCH_06748"
     CDS             complement(6865197..6865964)
                     /locus_tag="HCH_06748"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="hypothetical protein"
                     /protein_id="ABC33373.1"
                     /translation="MIKQIVRPLFTGKGPNFSELNVKECGIGDYLLRYKLPGNTIDIG
                     MPDAPVPSRVNLNADLFDSYDPKKLYNRTFVQMEFEWWAYRGLFLQGDSGLLSKMSLH
                     IDVNRINPNSPLGGSDLESLETYLREDYWDYYEAEKNIDGVPGSNWQKRYDFDNPDEV
                     RAKGYIPVRRLVLVLLPEIYVKERINDVEWLHYSIDGEGIAGTNITYYWAYPLTNNYY
                     LTFSFRTTTELGRNEQRYQRMLEDAKQIMSMVELCKG"
     gene            complement(6865961..6867109)
                     /locus_tag="HCH_06749"
     CDS             complement(6865961..6867109)
```

The goal here is to take each number of the 1st file's 1st column and see if that number appears in the second file. If yes, I want to print the line right above the match in the file2: "/locus_tag"

For example, if in file1 we have 6864294, and this number is also present on file2, then I'd like to print: /locus_tag="HCH_06747"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I have edited my question. I really am stuck because I know I must do this with awk, and I am still shaky with it...

Comment: Is your second file an established bioinformatics format? If so, which one? (It kind of looks like a partial genbank record...)

Comment: And if so, is the number you're looking for only going to show up in a complement tag?

Comment: It is a genbank file.

Comment: I think the number can be in either, complement or not

Comment: What do you mean by "or not"? Are you REALLY saying the number can be anywhere in file2 and you want to print whatever line is above the line that just happens to contain that number? That seems extremely unlikely - [edit] your question to clearly state which lines of file2 should be tested for a match.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tried this and I think it will work:

```
for i in $(cat file1 | awk -F " " '{print $1 '\n'; print $2}')
do
        grep -m1 $i file2 -A1 | tail -1

done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Amazing. Could you please just explain very briefly the code with hashtags? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, you'r welcome.
So the awk statement just separates the two numbers in each line, using the " " tag.
Then, I grep the file2 content using the number from file1, specifying only the first result (-m1), and taking the the row above it in the file (-A1). This leaves me with two rows, tail -1 is the one you looked for.

Comment: This answer contains several bugs and anti-patterns. It'll be very slow and fail cryptically given various input and/or environment values. Even if it didn't you certainly don't need a shell loop, 4 separate commands and 2 pipes just to do this task! You may have been hasty selecting this as the answer and so effectively telling everyone else not to bother posting other answers which would presumably include the right way to do this.

Comment: Also - won't this print the line AFTER the match instead of the line before it like you asked for?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough sample:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {                                    # hash file 1 to a
    a[$1]
    next
}
{
    q=$0                                     
    while(match($0,/[0-9]+/)) {              # find all numeric strings
        if((substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a)) # test if it is in a
            print p                          # and output previous record p
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)         # remove match from record
        }
    p=q                                      # store current record to p
}' file1 file2

                     /locus_tag="HCH_06747"
```

Comment: This looks pretty good! Thanks! This code also prints out DNA sequences though. I get this: /locus_tag="HCH_00354"
                     FRPTPTYSLHRIEHPAFRQAIANFLDEERAGVSEYMRDANAHLPFKQVE"
                     /locus_tag="HCH_00355"
                     NQFNKALRKTYESGEAREILAQRGLESVM"
                     /locus_tag="HCH_00356"
                     VDDNDGNDDSDEGNSGGDTNKGKDDGGGSLGLLSILALLTMRFARRRPM"

Comment: Sure.  It prints the previous line (in `p`) if it finds a matching numeric string in `a`.